# PHP echo multidimensional array inside a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am facing a little problem, and I think I am overlooking everything. I want a function that echoes a list of all categories in a database.

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "name";

$dbcon = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die(mysqli_error());

$multi_array = array();
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, 'SELECT * FROM `fdf_content`');
while($output = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $multi_array[] = $output;
}

function get_cats($multi_array){
    foreach($multi_array as $cats){
        echo $cats['category'];
    }
}
```

However, I get the following errors:

`Missing argument 1 for get_cats()`
and
`Undefined variable: multi_array`
`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

The problem is that the array is undefined in the function, but I don;t know why. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all you need to define this variable $multi_array = []; like this out of loop and foreach($multi_array as $cats) {}

Comment: Paste the right code.

Comment: where you call get_cats() in your code ?

Comment: Please include code where the erring functions exist.  Also what does print_r($multi_array); say?  Foreach's 'as' need space on left side.

Comment: I edited the post with the real code, I made some mistakes at editing vurnerable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [scope of a variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP is the function where it is created (initialized/modified). The variables created/modified outside any function are global variables and they are visibly only outside functions.

Let the function receive as arguments the values to work with:

```
function get_cats(array $categories){
    foreach ($categories as $cats){
        echo $cats, " "; 
    }
}
```

On the function invocation pass the desired value as argument:

```
$multi_array = array();
while ($output = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $multi_array[] = $output;
}

// Call the function that prints the content of $multi_array
get_cats($multi_array);
```

This way you can reuse the `get_cats()` function with different values:

```
$fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');

get_cats($fruits);
// Will print:
// apple banana orange
```

Comment: This code works great, although you need to change the `echo $cats,"";` to $cats['db_row_name'];`

Comment: Is there any way to make the function just be `get_cats();`? Since i use a specific database row name in the function, I cannot reuse it anyway in my case

Comment: If you want to write bad code there is always a way to do it. It's explained in the documentation page I linked into the answer how to do it (hint: `global`) but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Ah, if global is the only option, let's just keep it this way then ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting multidimensional array then use as follows:

```
function get_cats() {
foreach($multi_array as $cats->$value){
    echo $value; 
}}
```

if above is not working, test below:

```
 function get_cats() {
foreach($multi_array as $cats->$value){
    print_r($value); 
}}
```

To check the value is again array or object.

Comment: Undefined variable `$multi_array`. Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`.

Answer (score -1):

You having syntax error! 
try this one

```
       function get_cats(){
       foreach($multi_array as $cats)
       {
           echo $cats; 
       } 
       }
```

Comment: Undefined variable `$multi_array`. Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`.